# QLocalSocket - how to drop readings

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a `QLocalSocket` to transfer a `Measurement` struct at intervals to clients from a server program.

I set up the block and `QDataStream` then:

```
out.writeRawData(data, sizeof(Measurement));
out.device()->reset();
```

Then for each registered client:

```
clients_.at(i)->write(block);
clients_.at(i)->flush();
```

Then at the other end on signal `readyRead()`:

```
in.readRawData((char *) data, sizeof(Measurement));
```

What I want to happen is that if the client is not ready to receive when the measurement is sent it will skip a reading.
At the moment I get:

```
send 3
read 3
send 4
send 5
read 4
```

How can I get:

```
send 3
read 3
send 4
send 5
read 5
```

Comment: "client is not ready" ?? What does it mean? When something has been written to the client, you cannot avoid getting the data. It is already in the OS buffer and must be taken out. You can ignore the data if not ready for it yet, but you cannot "skip a reading".

Comment: So what to I need to clear or reset and is it at the server end or the client end?

Comment: There is nothing you can do on the server side, you have already `flush()`ed. The easiest way is to `in.skipRawData(sizeof(Measurement))` on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server has written something into the pipe (and `flush()`ed on top), then the client simply must read it out of the pipe, to be able to access the subsequent messages. If you don't want to do anything with the message you can simply `in.skipRawData(sizeof(Measurement))` on the client side. But if you want to avoid client getting ANY data, then you must prevent server from sending anything altogether. So some sort of **congestion control**. From the top of my head, i would let the client(s) signal something like `messageAcknowledgeReadyForNext()` or `notReadyToReceive()` and in the `clients_` iteration cycle, let's skip those clients which has sent *not ready* (and also such which are not known as sent at least one *acknowledge*).

Comment: Thanks, ``skipRawData()`` at the client end it is.